# What does "working the bill through" means?

Tags: meaning

> Extremely helpful role that he's played in working the bill through
>   the subcommittee mark and the full committee.

I saw this on C-SPAN, and I was wondering what "working the bill through the subcommittee mark" meant. Does it mean "working to get the bill through the subcommittee mark"? I find it odd that these two mean the same thing, because you would think they mean vastly different things.

Comment: A "subcommittee" is a smaller group than a "full committee".  You have to work (a bill) through the first before you can work through the second.  I'm not sure what "mark" refers to here, but it probably makes sense in context.

Comment: The "mark" here is as per *He dropped out of the marathon at the half-way mark*. It just means ***an identifiable intermediate stage*** (parliamentary bills often have to go through a "committee stage" before being formally voted on)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I guess what I meant is that I'm not sure why this person chose to say "subcommittee mark" but not "full committee mark".  Why is getting through a subcommittee a significant "mark"?  It may imply that getting the bill through the subcommittee is the more difficult hurdle, making the full committee a mere formality.  I feel like there's a nuance which might make sense with more context.

Comment: @Andrew: Well, unless someone's a party "whip" or similar, I don't think it's particularly meaningful to talk about working / steering / guiding a bill a bill through the ***voting*** stage. So effectively, what we're talking about is the "committee phase" of a bill, within which I suppose parliamentarians think in terms of a "subcommittee stage" before thing moves on to the [full] committee process.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isn't enough context to know what exactly the "subcommittee mark" implies.  It might just be a figure of speech, or it might suggest something more significant.

Comment: My guess: “subcommittee mark” means a stage during which the subcommittee *marks up* an immature draft, recommending improvements in wording and looking for provisions that could have unwelcome effects.